# Reload a ListView inside a Fragment after press back from Activity

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

i have a Fragment that load a ListView from a database and it is a Favorite list which user choosed before, when you click on the list item it starts an Activity and user will be able to see the detail and unfavorite the item the problem is when the user unfavorite an item and press back to back to fragment of fave list the view is still shows the first lodaded listview not the updated one. i want to know how the life cycle of fragment will work when you start an activity and come back again to know where to implement my

`adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Im using GoogleApiClient to get the location of user so i use to load the database in my onConnected methode:

```
    @Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
            mLocationClient, mLocationRequest, this);

    if (    ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // You need to ask the user to enable the permissions
    } else {
        LocationTracker tracker = new LocationTracker(getContext()) {
            @Override
            public void onLocationFound(@NonNull Location location) {
                currentLocation = location;
            }
            @Override
            public void onTimeout() {
            }
        };
        tracker.startListening();
    }
    if (currentLocation ==null) {
        currentLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mLocationClient);
    }

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                PERMISSION_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
    }
    if (currentLocation != null) {
        //Loading LAT LOng of //arkers on map
        for(int i=0; i<storedfavoritesitem.size(); i++) {
            FavoriteModel Faveitem = storedfavoritesitem.get(i);
            String locality = Faveitem.name;
            int id = Faveitem.id;
            double lat = Faveitem.lat;
            double lon =  Faveitem.lon;
            Location location = new Location("Beach");
            location.setLatitude(lat);
            location.setLongitude(lon);
            float distance = currentLocation.distanceTo(location);
            mResualt.add(new SearchResualtClass(id, distance / 1000, locality));
        }
        Comparator<SearchResualtClass > comperator = new Comparator<SearchResualtClass>()
        {
            @Override
            public int compare(SearchResualtClass  object1, SearchResualtClass  object2) {
                float First = object1.getDistance();
                float Second = object2.getDistance();
                return (First < Second ? -1 : (First == Second ? 0 : 1));
            }
        };
        Collections.sort(mResualt, comperator);
        adapter = new CustomAdapterSearch(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),mResualt);
        exList.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    exList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), FragmentBeach.class);
            intent.putExtra("array", jsonArray.toString());
            SearchResualtClass item = (SearchResualtClass) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            intent.putExtra("id", item.getId());
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: It depends on when you are loading data ... also `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` is not magic wand for refreshing

Comment: i uptadet my question with my codes

Comment: After Unfavorite, just do 3 more things-1: Remove that item from your List. 2: Remove that data from your database. 3: Reload the items on list when you need.

Comment: @DeepanshuHarbola of course but how and where? i tried some methods it didnt work

Comment: where you are performing the operation for unfavorite

Comment: @DeepanshuHarbola for people who made face the same problem, inside the Activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i solved it, i was `notifyDataSetChanged` but actually everything was loading from database so after i made change i should reload the list again from database and send the change notify so i implement the follwing code inside `OnResume`

```
 @Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    storedfavoritesitem = FavoriteModel.getAllFavorites();
    if (adapter!=null && currentLocation!=null) {
        mResualt.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < storedfavoritesitem.size(); i++) {
            FavoriteModel Faveitem = storedfavoritesitem.get(i);
            String locality = Faveitem.name;
            int id = Faveitem.id;
            double lat = Faveitem.lat;
            double lon = Faveitem.lon;
            Location location = new Location("Beach");
            location.setLatitude(lat);
            location.setLongitude(lon);
            float distance = currentLocation.distanceTo(location);
            mResualt.add(new SearchResualtClass(id, distance / 1000, locality));
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
  }
}
```

and it works fine now thanks every one

Comment: will fail when location  = null

Answer (score 0):

Move your code that loaded the datalist and feed it to adapter from `onCreate()` to `onResume()`

This will ensure your list will be reloaded whenever your fragment goes through pause-resume phase.

And as far as lifecycle is concerned, do read [Fragment Lifecycles][**1]

Update :*You will have to update `storedfavoritesitem`* then run following piece of code

```
if (currentLocation != null) {
        //Loading LAT LOng of //arkers on map
        for(int i=0; i<storedfavoritesitem.size(); i++) {
            FavoriteModel Faveitem = storedfavoritesitem.get(i);
            String locality = Faveitem.name;
            int id = Faveitem.id;
            double lat = Faveitem.lat;
            double lon =  Faveitem.lon;
            Location location = new Location("Beach");
            location.setLatitude(lat);
            location.setLongitude(lon);
            float distance = currentLocation.distanceTo(location);
            mResualt.add(new SearchResualtClass(id, distance / 1000, locality));
        }
        Comparator<SearchResualtClass > comperator = new Comparator<SearchResualtClass>()
        {
            @Override
            public int compare(SearchResualtClass  object1, SearchResualtClass  object2) {
                float First = object1.getDistance();
                float Second = object2.getDistance();
                return (First < Second ? -1 : (First == Second ? 0 : 1));
            }
        };
        Collections.sort(mResualt, comperator);
     if(adapter == null){
        adapter = new CustomAdapterSearch(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),mResualt);
        exList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }else{
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: i already tried it `@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (adapter != null) {
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }` it doesnt work for me

Comment: for that to work, your dataset must be updated, but it isn't. There are no changes in your dataset thats why there is no change in UI

Answer (score 0):

adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() will surely work. 
You have to call activity using startActivityForResult method and pass resultCode before your called activity is finished. Based on this resultCode, you can call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged().
Here is sample code. Pls replace accordingly.

```
startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == 1) {
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```